# How to take SUM of all COUNTs?

Tags: mysql

I am new to `mysql`.

I have a query to get count from different tables and it works okay. But, now I want to club all 3 query COUNT into 1 like SUM (COUNT1, COUNT2, COUNT3)

```
select COUNT(*) as count1, 0 as count2, 0 as count3 from table1 
UNION ALL 
select 0 as count1, COUNT(*) as count2, 0 as count3 from table2 
UNION ALL 
select 0 as count1, 0 as count2, COUNT(*) as count3 from table3
```

E.g. count1 = 10, count2 = 20 and count3 = 15

Then, I want to get sum = 45

Answer (score 4):

You can put the `UNION` in a subquery and then `SUM()` the counts. But there's no need to put them in separate columns in each unioned query.

```
SELECT SUM(count) AS total
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM table3
) AS subquery
```

Answer (score 3):

to get sum of all counts from you tables you can write  a query as

```
select 
(select COUNT(*) from table1) +
(select COUNT(*) from table2) +
(select COUNT(*) from table3) as total
```

Following your approach, you can wrap unioined query in as sub select and then apply sum on the results

```
SELECT SUM(count1) + SUM(count2) + SUM(count3) total
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count1, 0 AS count2, 0 AS count3 FROM table1 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 0 AS count1, COUNT(*) AS count2, 0 AS count3 FROM table2
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 0 AS count1, 0 AS count2, COUNT(*) AS count3 FROM table3
) t
```